# Warning: include(php/home.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in

Tags: php

**Hello**

**I got this problem:**

> Warning: include(php/home.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\index.php on line 54
>
> Warning: include(): Failed opening 'php/home.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\index.php on line 54

All the files are the same PHP folder directory, with the same name and all links go to the same error, i don't understand where and why it's wrong, help please.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
$op = $_GET["op"];
switch ($op)
{   
    case "alta":
        $contenido = "php/alta-contacto.php";
        $titulo = "Alta de Contacto";
        break;

    case "baja":
        $contenido = "php/baja-contacto.php";
        $titulo = "Baja de Contacto";
        break;

    case "cambios":
        $contenido = "php/cambios-contacto.php";
        $titulo = "Cambios a Contacto";
        break;

    case "consultas":
        $contenido = "php/consultas-contacto.php";
        $titulo = "Consultas a Contacto";
        break;

    default:
        $contenido ="php/home.php";
        $titulo ="Mis Contactos";
        break;
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title><?php echo $titulo; ?></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilo.css" />
        <script type="js/javascript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <section id="contenido">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a class="cambio" href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                <li><a class="cambio" href="?op=alta">Alta de Contacto</a></li>
                <li><a class="cambio" href="?op=baja">Baja de Contacto</a></li>
                <li><a class="cambio" href="?op=cambios">Cambios de Contacto</a></li>
                <li><a class="cambio" href="?op=consultas">Consultas de Contacto</a></li>
            </ul>   
        </nav>
                <section id="principal">
                    <?php include($contenido); ?>
                </section>
    </section>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If `index.php` still in the same directory as are all those file, just REMOVE `php/` and keep only the name of PHP files.

Comment: oh my god , so stupid, didn't see it. GOD BLESS YOU!

Comment: One often runs into this error, and to quickly troubleshoot it, follow these steps : stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Answer (score 1):

Are the files being included in a subdirectory (php)? Or are they in the same folder as the index.php?

If they are in the same folder, you need to change the include file name:

FROM

```
 $contenido = "php/alta-contacto.php";
```

TO

```
 $contenido = "alta-contacto.php";
```

Comment: I have started a troubleshooting checklist for this frequent error here : stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507